# Is default username and password NULL for PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, account

I have installed postgresql through homebrew.

There was a default database named "postgres". I also created a new database by running the command "create " from the terminal. However, postgresql never prompted me to set up any user name and password. When I use a GUI (Datagrip) to navigate these databases, I can keep the username and password field blank while connecting to these databases.

I am new to postgresql and I know MySQL. In MySQL, there is a root account from where I can create new accounts with certain privileges. Is the default setting in postgresql NULL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, postgres come only with login (peer) authentication. You should use psql (postgres command line client) to add a new login and password. To access psql, run:

```
sudo -u postgres psql
```

Inside psql, create a role with the command:

```
postgres=# CREATE USER myuser with password 'mypass';
```

Finally, grant permission on some database to this new role:

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE mydb to myuser;
```

After that, you will be able to access the database using this new user in DataGrip.

Another (more advanced) option, is to edit the `pg_hba.conf` file to enable local other authentication methods. This page may help you: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/auth-methods.html

Comment: I cannot run `sudo -u postgres psql`. It gives `sudo: unknown user: postgres`

Comment: It's because you are using MacOS. Try just `psql` and look if you get logged in